# Resizing 3d objects using React.js and Three.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d

I'm creating a simple portfolio using 3d objects in React.js and Three.js, I have asked a 3d designer to create me some 3d objects in Blender and he sent me the files as gltf, the objects are working perfect in the website, but I'm facing one problem, I'm trying to resize the 3d object and whenever I change the scale of the object after refreshing the page the changes go back to default, why is this happening and how can I change the scale of the objects ?
This is the 3d object after converting it to a React compononent :

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function Model(props) {
const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/tsLogo-transformed.glb");
return (
<group {...props} dispose={null}>
  <mesh
    geometry={nodes.Cube.geometry}
    material={materials.PaletteMaterial001}
    position={[0, 0, 0.08]}
    scale={[0.304, 0.304, 0.063]}
  />
  </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/tsLogo-transformed.glb");
```

This is the component where I'm calling the component that has the 3d object :

```
import { OrbitControls, Stage } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import React from "react";
import TsLogo from "./TsLogo";

const TS = () => {
return (
<Canvas>
  <Stage environment="city" intensity={0.6}>
    <TsLogo />
  </Stage>
  <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} autoRotate={true} />
</Canvas>
 );
};

export default TS;
```

and here's the tree of the files of my project :

[image]

I have marked the two components `TS.jsx`  is the component which has the canvas and renders the 3d object, `TsLogo.jsx` is the component after converting the gltf to a React component, and also the tsLogo-transformed .glb is the file that I need to have for the object to have its options, I can't open the file though